# Resizing Image in Jsp and Displaying muliple images in Jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a two part question .I am trying to retrieve image (blob) from my Database and display it on my jsp .I have be able to retrieve image and display it on Jsp but the problem is a new page is getting created with the original image size. I have tried resizing the image in the jsp but ,I couldnt resize it.  I have also read it that it is not possible to resize the image in the Jsp since its just the view . How can this be achieved in servlets. Below is my Jsp code and servlet code respectively .

**jsp**

```
<form action="Display">
    <c:forEach items="${imagenames}" var="imagename">
        <img src="images/${imagename}" height="30" width="30">
    </c:forEach>
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
</form>
```

**Servlet**

```
ResultSet rs =null;
Product p= new Product();
rs=newController.getProduct( p,0,0);
try {
    if (rs.next()){
        try {
            byte[] content = rs.getBytes("ProductImage");
           // response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(imageName));
            response.setContentLength(content.length);
            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            response.getOutputStream().write(content);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Display.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

The second part is how do I display multiple images in jsp.

servlet Code:http://balusc.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/fileservlet.html

I am using netbean 8.0.2 ,servlet version is 3.1

Any help would be appreciated ..
thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to create some sort of a gallery or whatever, getting several images from the list. You can use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and its grid system to make as many columns and rows as you want and it will resize them according to the row's and column's width/heigth and amount of columns etc.

The code then would look like:

```
  <c:if test="${!empty imageList}">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="row">
            <c:forEach items="${imageList}" var="image">
                <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 wrapper">
                    <img class="img-responsive imgClip"src="/something/getImg${image.imageId}" />
                </li>
    </c:forEach>

         </ul>
    </div>
```

PS. You need firstly to add a bootstrap to your project (you can add it as a maven dependcy if you use maven)